# Json serialization in NServiceBus 7 for Sql transport requires an assembly qualified name

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nservicebus

I'm upgrading my sql tranport endpoints of NServiceBus from version 6 to 7.
The first change I had to make is the `NServiceBus.JsonSerializer` because it is obsolete.

I've changed my endpoint configuration to use `NServiceBus.NewtonsoftSerializer`:

```
endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>()
```

This change throws an exception of type:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON 'MyAssembly.MyEvents.MyEvent' was not resolved
```

**First approach**:

To solve it I have to enter my Assembly in my json `$type` property from all my triggers:

```
insert into [MyEndpointQueue] (Id , Recoverable, Headers, Body) 
... 
values (.... 
convert(varbinary(MAX), '{"$type":"MyAssembly.MyEvents.MyEvent, MyAssembly.Events" ..... }
```

**Second approach**:

I've been trying to implement my custom `ISerializationBinder` like this:
https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/newtonsoft#compatibility-with-the-core-json-serializer-use-of-type-requires-an-assembly-qualified-name

This approach forces to refactor all my services to pass the `Type[] messageTypes` array.

Is there a third approach that works as `NServiceBus.JsonSerializer` did?

That is,

1. I'd like to keep my triggers without the name of the assembly,
2. And not have to specify all my types of events for each service on my endpoints configuration.

Comment: See if this might help? https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/newtonsoft#compatibility-with-the-core-json-serializer-use-of-type-requires-an-assembly-qualified-name

Comment: That link is my second approach. It forces me to pass an array of types. In version 6 that wasn't necessary.